# std::thread::hardware_concurrency only detects one physical processor's cores

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio

I have a dual-socket motherboard, with two physical processors each having 18 physical cores (36 logical). In Window's Task Manager, I have a total of 72 logical cores. In BIOS, both physical CPU's are listed as expected, with hyper-threading enabled.

When the following is run in *Visual Studio Community 2015* and compiled in C++, I am only given 36 as an answer:

```
std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

Furthermore, when I execute multi-threaded code using 72 threads, I have found in Windows Performance Monitor that the C++ program is using only one of the two NUMA nodes, leaving the other physical processor untouched.

Any help to expose all 72 cores would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try a different compiler?

Comment: Maybe the OS is set to run a given each process on only one core to prevent cache thrashing, at least by default?